# How can I know if a new directory is added or removed in git repository

Tags: git

I have a requirement in my team to write pre-commit hook in git which should restrict any addition or deletion of directories.

As git always considers files to create a new directory users can simply add a required or dummy file and  add it however before commit my pre-commit hook should compare the known directory structure in remote and return non zero number if violated.

`git log -n1 --pretty="format:" --name-only` is giving me the list of changes in the pre commit however need some ideas how I can compare the directory structure alone.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before git does not directionless by them self.

The reason for that is the git ***`tracks content`*** and directories does not have any content they are just a metadata.

Once we cleared this out the **question remains**:

## ***How can i track `addition or deletion of directories`***

The simple answer is that you cant since git does not track directories.
What you can do is to execute a script (in your hook) which will print out the current directories and then strip out the directory from all the commited files and verify that the directory already exist.

```
# get a list of all the directories 
git ls-files | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq
```

Once you have this list use it to verify that the commited file are all added only to folders which are in this list.

---

As you can see this script print out only directories.

[image]

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it explained how to determine a "directory that already exist[s]". The list of files from `git ls-files` only returns files for the current working directory and index, but as far as I can't tell, can't be applied to another revision (to build a list for comparison).

Comment: Elegant use of a little-known git command plus the power of bash!

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it may seem, directories are not stored in git. The only directories you will get on a `git clone` are those directories required to store the files that are stored within the repository, each file being stored with its path. Therefore all you can do is reject *files* with paths that fall outside the desired directory structure. Judicious use of `dirname` or equivalent in your favourite language, combined with matching this against your template, would therefore be helpful.